# Error in Upload File from website to FTP server in ASP.net MVC3.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
While uploading Zip file more than 20MB into FTP server, the Error [The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive] raised in suituation.
here i attached the code. for where the exception raise
 {ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);
                ftpReq.KeepAlive = false;
                ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                ftpReq.UseBinary = true;
                FileStream fs = fileInfo.Open(FileMode.OpenOrCreate,    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Stream ftpstream = ftpReq.GetRequestStream();
                ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
           **`ftpstream.Close();`****---->  the Error Appeared in the suituation while closing FTP connection .i applied solution for the problem from website .
     i have set Timeout Property of FTP. {ftpreq.Timeout=300000[5min] } above Web Request methods. In My Local Host it' allow to upload upto 50. while uploading file in  Production it allows 30 MB file to upload. if we upload more than 30 MB shows error "Server time out problem"i have tried lot of testing, but i could not fix the issue.
```

Please provide Correct solution Why we can't upload more file size. for that what we have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to changed the default upload size in your webconfig

Like this

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="size in kbs" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The default is 4096 (= 4 MB).

Comment: HI i already set  value<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200(50Mb)" />